# Colors doesn't change using Highcharts.setOptions

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have a page displaying multiple charts. I set the theme to be used for all charts according to the code below:

```
Highcharts.theme = {
    colors: ["#E37B25", "F5BF36", "#7C1C1D", "#458744", "#3E7FA3", "#0C9BD7", "#265667"],
    ...
}

Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.theme);
```

I then have a bunch of specific options for each chart and create the charts in a set interval.

```
var chart;
chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartOptions);
```

The problem is that every time a chart is created it has the first color in the array, instead of rotating through them. I thought `setOptions()` would manage this for each chart but apparently it doesn't. How can this be done so every time i create a new chart using `new Highcharts.Chart(chartOptions)` it selects the next color in the array?

Comment: The chart `colors` is the array of colors used by each series in a chart - not each chart on a page. You would need to iterate over that `colors` array when building your chart to assign a color (assuming each of your charts has a single series).

Answer (score 0):

As @wegeld commented, `colors` in the array are given as list option which are used by **series** elements of the chart rather than **charts** in successive manner.

But if that is the requirement, you can create a `colorIterator` and do following. I have create a codepen example for you here: https://codepen.io/mikhilraj/pen/KrjzxN/

```
var colorIterator = 0;

function getColor() {
    var color = Highcharts.getOptions().colors[colorIterator%Highcharts.getOptions().colors.length];
    colorIterator++;
    return color;
};
```

And add following in as options while creating the chart.

```
series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [0, 1, 4, 4, 5, 2, 3, 7],
    fillColor:  getColor()
}]
```